# How to build a site on Drupal which does not contain Drupal logo

Tags: drupal

I tried to built a simple Drupal site containing one line of text. But once I added it, it looks like I'm still using Drupal environment. How can I built or see sites which do not show Drupal logo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logo display is controlled in theme settings at admin/build/themes/settings in Drupal 6 or admin/appearance/settings in Drupal 7. Under "TOGGLE DISPLAY", just uncheck the "Logo" box. You can also go to the individual theme settings (e.g. admin/appearance/settings/bartik) and select a different logo.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [tutorial](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/theming/howto/change-the-favicon) for changing the favicon in Drupal. If you install the [Metatag module](https://www.drupal.org/project/metatag), there are more configuration options for setting the default site icon for mobile devices & tablets in HTML. Also check out the [Responsive Favicons](https://www.drupal.org/project/responsive_favicons) module for advanced logo, icon, & favicon display options.